# How to parse Json file in swift for 2 collection Views?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview

I have JSON file like this

```
{
  "dicts": [
    {
      "main": "",
      "note1": "",
      "note2": "",
      "note3": "",
      "note4": ""
    },
    {
      "main": "",
      "note1": "",
      "note2": "",
      "note3": "",
      "note4": "",
      "note5": ""
    },
    {
      "main": "",
      "note1": "",
      "note2": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

My App has 2 `view controllers` each having `collection view`. In first `collection view` I will display JSON data `main` for each `cell` and when I click `main` I have trouble setting `note` data for that respective `main` content in each `cell`. All I came able to call any one `note` value.

**Model:**

```swift
struct SecPage {
    var note1:String?
    var note1:String?
    var note2:String?
    var note3:String?
    var note4:String?
    var note5:String?
}

static func downSec () -> [SecPage] {
    let jsonFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "info", withExtension: "json")
    let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: jsonFile!)
    var noteArray = [SecPage]()

    do{
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .mutableContainers) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
            let name = jsonResult["dicts"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
            for note in name!{
                let note1 = note["note1"] as? String
                let note2 = note["note2"] as? String
                let note3 = note["note3"] as? String
                let note4 = note["note4"] as? String
                let note5 = note["note5"] as? String
                let noteinfo = SecPage(note1: note1 ,note2:    note2,note3: note3, note4: note4, note5: note5, note6: note6)
                noteArray.append(noteinfo)    }}  } catch{print("note not found")}
    return noteArray
}
```

**View**

```
class CollectionViewCell2: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var names: UILabel!

    func updateUIsec(data:dataObj)  {
        names.text = data.note1
    }
}
```

How to update in cell when I can able to enter only one data in `name.text` and how to efficiently use `Model class` to retrieve `json` file and send to `view`.

Comment: Can you change your JSON? It isn't very useful.  Instead of having `note1` `note2` etc, you should have `notes` which is an array of strings.

Comment: So how to update in `cell label` if I have array of `notes`?

Comment: Well, you would have a struct `SecPage` that had a `main` `String` property and a `notes` `[String]` property.  Parse your JSON into an array of these structs.  You then pass the appropriate element from the array to your second view controller.

Comment: Yeah I did but I have to display all `notes` in  each cell . `names.text = data.note?[0]` will be same as what I done there.

Comment: Also don't use `.mutableContainers` when parsing a `JSON` object in `Swift`, since it has no effect.

Comment: @Digs: I'm having trouble deciphering your intent here. Is your question about how to send note1/note2/note3/note4/note5 to the 2nd VC once the user selects a cell from the 1st VC ?

Comment: @nathan Much likely how to display in a cell of 2nd VC .I have those `Note` data as a string now like suggested by @Paulw .

Comment: Are you using segues for your VC1->VC2 transition ?

Comment: @nathan yes....

Comment: ...It's not clear whether the issue is JSON parsing or passing data between ViewControllers or UICollectionViewController -> Cell (Each of those situations have different answers and are probably dupes).

Comment: @nathan In the `collection view Class`as shown in question `data'  has all the `note` values . I need those values to be in the 2nd VC where as I can put only 1 value there `names.text = data.note1` or `names.text = data.note[i]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unsure if this is what you are looking for, your question is too broad and hard to understand. Comment the answer and I'll update it as needed ;)

VC1:

```
class VC1: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var modelData = [SecPage]()
    var selectedItem: SecPage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate   = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        //collectionView.register... // Register UICollectionView cell subclass
        modelData = SecPage.downSec()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let secPage = modelData[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeue...
        cell.textLabel.text = secPage.main

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let destination = segue.destination as? VC2{
            destination.selectedItem = selectedItem
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedItem = modelData[indexPath.row]
        performSegue...
    }
}
```

VC2:

```
class VC2: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var selectedItem: SecPage? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate   = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        //collectionView.register... // Register UICollectionView cell subclass
        modelData = SecPage.downSec()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeue...
        cell.updateUIsec(data: selectedItem!)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Cell:

```
class CollectionViewCell2: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var names: UILabel!

    func updateUIsec(data: SecPage)  {
        names.text = data.note1
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.... The whole problem  was with one stupid thing is that in 2nd VC instead of doing `var selectedItem: SecPage!` as you shown I created array instance `var selectedItem=[ SecPage]()`